# Boolean not evaluating correctly?

Tags: java, boolean

So I'm trying to do a school project (a simple leap year tester) but my boolean statements do not seem to be working. My code looks like:

```
    public class Year{

      int year_input;



public Year(int year_input){

}


public boolean isLeapYear(){
    // your code here 
    if (year_input % 4 ==0){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
}
}
```

And it has to work with the included class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYearTester{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a year");
    int year_input = input.nextInt();

    Year theYear = new Year(year_input);

    if (theYear.isLeapYear())
        System.out.println("That's a leap year!");
    else
        System.out.println("That's not a leap year!");
}
}
```

But for some reason, but console is saying that all years are leap years, even if they're obviously not.
[False Leap Years](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFiHX.png) (Picture)

Any help?

Comment: You didn't assign the parameter `year_input` to the instance variable `year_input` in your constructor, so the instance variable is always `0`.

Comment: And as a side note, it's clearer to just say `return (year_input % 4 == 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor, you need to assign the parameter to your instance variable.

```
public Year(int year_input){
    this.year_input = year_input;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. :) Good luck with the semester!